# Programmatically created back button does not show up in navigation bar?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

To make this simple, because of the app design I cannot use an embedded navigation controller and must instead use a manual back button on the view controller to move back to the previous one. As far as I know, the previous view controllers push to this one programmatically as well. So I found some great code for a button on many different questions here, and I wrote it for this app. Problem is, when I run the program the Bar Button Item I created does not show up. The code shows no errors and I am confused as to why nothing is showing up. I'll include images and the code to make this as clear as possible. As always thank you for any help you can provide!!!

Code Used:

```
@IBOutlet weak var roomImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var locationLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var roomName: UINavigationItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Back Button Code

    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Back",style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(DetailView.back(sender:)))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = backButton
    navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false

    // Hide da tab bar

    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    // Enter data from other view controllers

    //roomName.title = stringPassed
    roomImage.image = imagePassed
    locationLabel.text = locationPassed

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

// Back Button Action

func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    if let navigationController = self.navigationController {

        navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)

    }
}
```

}

Actual Storyboard with Navigation Bar

[image]

When the app is run

[image]

Could it be I didn't make something an outlet or something of that sort? Thank you!!

Storyboard layout

[image]

Tree Model of Detail View (The one with the navigation bar issue)

[image]

EDIT: Still not working but the links and ideas you gave have given me plenty of new ideas and options to explore until a more concrete answer presents itself. Thank you!!!

Comment: I wouldn't have preferred this way. Why can't use a navigationController.

Comment: If I used navigation controllers it would take 3 instead of one because 3 different view controllers are pushing to this single view. All rooted in a tab view. If you think there is an easier way I am all ears.

Comment: @Frank_Cerny Can you show your storyboard structure. Have you added NavigationItem by dragging from the controls to viewController?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean (new to development and learning slowly) The storyboard structure is up there and I believe I added a navigation item by dragging it onto the navigation bar? Nothing changed when I added it though.

Comment: @Frank_Cerny Are you moving to Title screen using `navigationController.pushViewController`?

Comment: I believe so if I am correct. The middle of the 3 vertical view controllers pushes to the far right view with the image view with: navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true) because it has a navigation controller embedded in. And then the one on top and below the middle use: self.show(myVC, sender: self) because they do not have a navigation controller embedded in. myVC is the object that points to the view all the way to the right

Comment: @Frank_Cerny See my answer once and do as I mentioned in answer remove the navigationBar that you have added in storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `NavigationBar` that you have drag from the Controls Library panel to your `ViewController`. When you set the `navigationItem` using `self.navigationItem` it will not reference to that `navigationBar` item because it has no connection with it.

When you push your `ViewController` using `navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)` it will automatically show `NavigationBar` on the `myVC` screen.

Comment: I did what you said, and the button only shows up when I use the push view AND have the navigation bar shown in the navigation controller. However, for the other 2 views that are not rooted in the navigation controller there is still no back button. Your answer makes a lot of sense and I trying out whatever I can to make this work. Also if I turn the navigation bar off when the single view rooted in it pushes to the detailView, nothing happens as usual.

Comment: @Frank_Cerny If you loss the navigationController then navigationbar will not show.

Comment: The whole point is to create a back button that works for views not rooted in the navigation controller, I can make back buttons with view controllers all day, but that implementation does not work for this problem. Your answer only worked for the navigation controller rooted one which was not the issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show how did you push to DetialView Controller 
I tired programmatically 
like this

```
func showDetialViewController(){
let detialViewController = UIViewConroller()
navigationController?.pushViewController(detialViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Answers are meant to answer the question on hand not to raise more questions.

Comment: One view controller pushes like you said and the other 2 show, check the comment above.